# Swift: Toolbar items appear at random positions

Tags: swift, toolbar, items

I'm currently implementing an app with a custom toolbar. The toolbar I will add programatically. I want the toolbar to appear with a image and a text, some like this:
[image: Image with text below]

Unfortunally the toolbar I wrote looks as follows:
[image]

and I'm not really shure why it doesnt work.
The code I wrote looks as follows:

```
  self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false


    let customButton : UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    customButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Home"), for: .normal)
    customButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let customButton1 : UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    customButton1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Account"), for: .normal)
    customButton1.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let customButton2 : UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    customButton2.setImage((UIImage(named: "Ball")), for: .normal)
    customButton2.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit


    customButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    customButton1.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    customButton2.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

    let customBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customButton as UIView)
    let customBarButtonItem1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customButton1 as UIView)
    let customBarButtonItem2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customButton2 as UIView)

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append( UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil))
    items.append( customBarButtonItem)
    items.append( UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil) )
    items.append( customBarButtonItem1)
    items.append( UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil) )
    items.append( customBarButtonItem2)



    self.toolbarItems = items
```

I know the code looks terrible but I just want to make it work and no solution I found has worked for me.

Also maybe if someone knows a good tutorial on how to build toolbars programatically I would appreciate the link. :)

Comment: I think you should use tabBar instead of toolbar. This way you can display icon and text.

Answer (score 1):

This custom PagerController may be helpful, I have used this to show tabs in the top of view with titles only, but there is an option to add icons and bottom of the ViewController also.

https://github.com/StepicOrg/stepik-ios/blob/master/PagerController.swift